# Pass function to generic function

Tags: scala, generics

I have the following code that I would like to abstract for additional types:

```
val users = Set[User](new User(1, "tyler"), new User(2, "phil"), new User(3, "quan"))
val groups = Set[Group](new Group(1, 10, 1), new Group(2, 20, 3))


def myFind(user: User)(implicit g: Group): Boolean = {
     user.id == g.adminID
}

val combined = groups.map(implicit g => {
    val admin = users.find(myFind)

    // Do something with relation
    g.toString + " " + admin.toString
})

println(combined)
```

What I would like to do is turn this into a function.  What I have so far is:

```
def myFunc[A, B](s1: Set[A], s2: Set[B], f: (B) => Boolean): Set[String] = {
    s1.map(implicit t1 => {
        val rel = s2.find(f)
        t1.toString + " " + rel.to
    })
}

myFunc(users, groups, myFind)
```

---

There are two compilation errors:

```
Could not find implicit value for parameter g: Sets.Group
myFunc(users, groups, myFind)
               ^
```

And

```
Not enough arguments for method myFind: (implicit g: Sets.Group)Boolean.
Unspecified value parameter g.
myFunc(users, groups, myFind)
               ^
```

---

EDIT:  Full code:

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String)
case class Group(id: Int, membersCount: Int, adminID: Int)

object Playground {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val users = Set[User](new User(1, "tyler"), new User(2, "phil"), new User(3, "quan"))
        val groups = Set[Group](new Group(1, 10, 1), new Group(2, 20, 3))


        def myFind(user: User)(implicit g: Group): Boolean = {
            user.id == g.adminID
        }

        val combined = groups.map(implicit g => {
            val admin = users.find(myFind)

            // Do something with relation
            g.toString + " " + admin.toString
        })

        println(combined)

        myJoin(users, groups, myFind)

    }

    def myJoin[A, B](s1: Set[A], s2: Set[B], f: (B) => Boolean): Set[String] = {
        s1.map(implicit t1 => {
            val rel = s2.find(f)
            t1.toString + " " + rel.to
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you declaring the implict `Group` variable?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I added the full script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in `myFunc` at the point where you call `s2.find(f)` there is no information that `f` takes any implicit parameters. And you can't express this kind of information in the type signature of a function argument.

I believe, your best bet is to have `myFunc` take a function from both `A` and `B` to `Boolean` (either `(A, B) => Boolean` or `A => B => Boolean`).

For example:

```
def myFunc[A, B](s1: Set[A], s2: Set[B], f: A => B => Boolean): Set[String] =
  s1.map { t1 =>
    val rel = s2.find(f(t1))
      t1.toString + " " + rel.to
  }
```

Then for this definition of `myFunc`, you can pass `myFind` to it in one of those ways:

```
myFunc(users, groups, (u: User) => { implicit g: Group => myFind(u)})
```

Or

```
myFunc(users, groups, (u: User) => (g: Group) => myFind(u)(g))
```

Or define a function without implicit parameters and pass it directly:

```
def myFind2(user: User)(g: Group): Boolean = user.id == g.adminID
myFunc(users, groups, myFind2)
```

Or if you have a function from two arguments you can pass it to `myFunc` using `curried` method:

```
def myFind3(user: User, g: Group): Boolean = user.id == g.adminID
myFunc(users, groups, (myFind3 _).curried)
```